# How to copy/fwd all email to 1 email address in cPanel?

Tags: email, cpanel

I have 4 email accounts for a domain. I need to copy/foward all email to an external email address. Is there a way to do this in cPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Email section of CPanel, click **Forwarders**.

1. In **Forwarders for an account**, click **Add Forwarder** button.
2. On the new page enter the address, account name, and select domain from the drop-down list.
3. Select **Forward to email address** option and enter the email address in the edit box..
4. Click **Add Forwarder** to confirm.

Repeat the procedure for other accounts.